# Delete a file selected by user from Files Directory in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, file

Hi I have the following code to delete a file from the files directory as a function. But it seems to work a few times when single filename string is passed but when I use it as a function and pass filenames, its not working.
The code is as follows.
Im using Xcode 9.2 with Swift 4.1

```
//USAGE
//User Clicks on a delete button and that will present an Alert Dialog with a list of files and user clicks on the file he/she would like to delete
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@IBAction func deleteConfigAction(_ sender: Any) {
    //---
    //---

    //Another function is called to list all files in the files directory and then store it into a string variable
    var file1: String = "Empty"

    //Calling another function to load all files present
    var userFilesPresent : [String] = listFilesPresent()!

    //For Example
    file1 = userFilesPresent[0]

    //---
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete File", message: "Select a file to be deleted", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: file1, style: .default,handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in

        self.deleteFileSelected(fileName: file1)

        print("file deleted =",file1)

    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))

    // show the alert
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------
//FUNCTION

func deleteFileSelected(fileName:String) -> [String]? {
    //Set Files directory path

    let mypath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)

    if mypath.count > 0 {

        let directoryPath = mypath[0]

        //Filter for txt files
        let searchfilePath = NSString(format:"%@/%@.txt", directoryPath, fileName) as String

        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: searchfilePath) {
            do {
                //file exists, now try deleting the file
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: searchfilePath)
                print("File deleted")
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: the code above doesnt attempt to remove multiple files at once. so we can't really help with that part. I would suggest that you unit test your code or at least add some debug output. maybe print something like `[DEBUG] - Attempting to remove file at path: \(path)` in your file exists at path add an else and debug (or even better use a guard statement)

Comment: Why you dont try this single line code to delete file using fileURL try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileURL)

Comment: @ManishMahajan I have tried to use, 
            do {
                try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: file1)
            }
            catch let error as NSError {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }

Comment: @ManishMahajan And the error states no such files or directory exists. Thanks for your response though

Comment: Means you are not passing right path.... search manually whether file exist or not locally by getting file path through debug section

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to create file path by appending filename to base url for your directory

```
func delete(fileName : String)->Bool{
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let docDir = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    let filePath = docDir.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    do {
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: filePath)
        print("File deleted")
        return true
    }
    catch {
        print("Error")
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Perfect Thanks, its working now and I see my mistake.